# How do I reverse the order of integration in $\int _{-2}^4\int _{\frac{y^2}{2}-3}^{y+1}\:x\:dxdy?$

Tags: integration

How do I reverse the order of integration for this following problem?

$$\int _{-2}^4\int _{\frac{y^2}{2}-3}^{y+1}\:x\:dxdy$$

I did  $x-1\le y\le\sqrt{2x+6}$ and $-3\le x\le5$ but it's not giving me the correct answer.

Comment: It is correct, I copied this from the textbook.

Comment: I suggest that you draw a picture of the domain on which the integral takes place. That will ease an understanding of the question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=reverse+the+order+of+integration

Answer (score 1):

You want to consider the region bounded by the curves $x=y+1$ and $x= \frac {y^2}{2}-3$

It helps to graph the region
[image]

If you want to integrate with respect to $y$ first, I suggest drawing a vertical line segment through the graph and finding equations that represent the endpoints. (If you are integrating with respect to $x$ first make a horizontal line.)  As you can see, where you choose to make your vertical line makes a difference as in one part of the graph the lower bound is $-\sqrt{2x+6}$, and in another it is $x-1.$

This means breaking the region in two.

$\int_{-3}^{-1} \int_{-\sqrt{2x+6}}^\sqrt{2x+6} x\ dy\ dx + \int_{-1}^5\int_{x-1}^{\sqrt{2x+6}} x\ dy\ dx$

Comment: Ohh I see!!! thank you soo much